# Apply vimrc changes without restarting

Tags: vim

How can I have changes in my vimrc take effect without restarting VIM?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can just source it, like this:

```
:so ~/.vimrc
```

Also, for convenience, it usually gets mapped to something quicker to type:

```
nmap <silent> <leader>sv :so $MYVIMRC<CR>
```

And then of course, it would be nice to open vimrc a little quicker:

```
nmap <silent> <leader>ev :e $MYVIMRC<CR>
```

Comment: hey, is 'so' the same thing as 'source'??? i remember that 'source .bashrc' or smt similar worked for shell...

Comment: @playcat yes and no... ``:so`` is shorthand for ``:source``, but it is a different command than the bash ``source`` builtin.  The difference of course that vim's ``:source`` runs a vim script in the current vim session, while bash's ``source`` runs a bash script in the current bash session.

Comment: @Peter BTW, what is the meaning of <silent> and <leader>?

Comment: <silent> just means the command isn't echoed to the status line when it runs, and <leader> is the key used as a prefix to allow you to define shortcuts on most keys. I use ',' so I type ',sv' to reload my vimrc.

Comment: What if I _want_ the command to echo? Removing silent still doesn't let me know that the file was sourced. Doing plain ':so $MYVIMRC' from normal mode still doesn't echo anything... I could swear it did before...

Answer (score 15):

You can automate this by creating an autocmd that sources the .vimrc file every time it is saved:

```
autocmd BufWritePost .vimrc so %
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `~/.vimrc` so if you edit a .vimrc elsewhere (perhaps in a vcs repo), you don't accidentally source it?  Or even `$MYVIMRC` instead?

Comment: auto but not suggest, because it cause more time after :write, even dead after change to $MYVIMRC. nmap solution is suggest.

Answer (score 5):

If you are editing it,just type:

```
:so %
```

Comment: prefered ``nnoremap <silent><buffer> <leader>so :w<CR>:so %<CR>``